# New to RDLC integration to MVC View #Error when rendering some fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, rdlc

I have recently created my first RDLC report using Visual Studio 2010 to my MVC application.

I used Report Wizard to create Report1.rdlc and I run the following controller code to render output to a PDF.

My data source when the report runs references Site Object in my Model. Everything runs fine but 2 of the 4 columns in the output are rendered as #Error

Both columns have data in them for every record, there are no nulls

The only thing that makes the 2 #Error columns different from the ones that render is that they are a level down the model. i.e. of the 4 columns :

1st field SiteDescription renders OK
2nd field SiteOperator renders value as #Error for each row
3rd field SiteStatus renders value as #Error for each row
4th field CapacityMW renders OK

NB: SiteOperator is Site.SiteOperator.Operator. Similar for 3rd field. The 1st and forth are fields in the Site table (i.e. top level of model in this case)

QUESTION: Is there something else developer has to do to allow RDLC to work with existing objects from the Model? i.e. I noticed the report wizard creates a Report1.rdlc.xml file, perhaps this has to be modified, I have ran out of ideas on this one. Any comments greatly appreciated

Here is my controller code :

```
        private void RenderReport(string ReportPath, object Model)
    {

        var localReport = new LocalReport { ReportPath = ReportPath };

        var reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", Model);
        localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

        var reportType = "PDF";
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string fileNameExtension;

        //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType
        //http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx
        string deviceInfo =
        "<DeviceInfo>" +
        "  <OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat>" +
        "  <PageWidth>8.5in</PageWidth>" +
        "  <PageHeight>11in</PageHeight>" +
        "  <MarginTop>0.5in</MarginTop>" +
        "  <MarginLeft>1in</MarginLeft>" +
        "  <MarginRight>1in</MarginRight>" +
        "  <MarginBottom>0.5in</MarginBottom>" +
        "</DeviceInfo>";

        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streams;
        byte[] renderedBytes;

        //Render the report
        renderedBytes = localReport.Render(
            reportType,
            deviceInfo,
            out mimeType,
            out encoding,
            out fileNameExtension,
            out streams,
            out warnings);

        //Clear the response stream and write the bytes to the outputstream
        //Set content-disposition to "attachment" so that user is prompted to take an action
        //on the file (open or save)
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = mimeType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=foo." + fileNameExtension);
        Response.BinaryWrite(renderedBytes);
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: I'm thinking when the wizard builds the dataset it uses the object iEnumerable and just creates a 2 dimensional array. That would explain why only the top level fields appear. This being the case then I guess its stored procedures I should use.Surely this must be a feature we will get in the future, referencing the model already there from the controller and assigning an Object rather than a 2d result set. Too used to MVC and forgetting RDLC is way behind. Would you guys agree on this?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to look at when receiving "#Error" responses in RDLC is the Output/Debug tab in Visual Studio.  This should have a specific error message for each error the reporting engine received while rendering the report.  While not always the most intuitive messages in the world, they should at least point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I use RDLCs in MVC with models that originated with a C# class generated by Entity Framework (using POCO object template).

Now, my class is a relatively "flat" class with just properties (nullables, numerics, strings, DateTimes, etc.) and no collections of other objects so that might make a difference.

I created my RDLCs without the use of the wizard, but found that to do so with the designer in MVC I had to add a .aspx to the project for the designer to work.  I also just have public static methods in a mock class that return the IEnumerables of the types I use for consumption by the report data source wizards and such.

I also use EF to populate my data so it definitely doesn't need stored procedures:

```
var data = dal.PrintFriendlies.Where( p => p.ApplicationId == applicationId );
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add( new ReportDataSource( "DataSourceName" , data ) );
```

I also am returning the PDF bytes so your code looks very close to what I use (I use both datasources and parameters, plus subreports).

You don't describe what your class structure is like, but I think it has issues with hierarchichal structures so you may need to flatten it to something the report writer prefers.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get the reports working well. I switched to using a stored procedure and calling it from the controller. I placed the RDLC file in the view and render it directly to PDF. Really happy with this since I never had to touch routing in the MVC app and I never had to ADD any ASP.NET pages with controls or anything like that.Very neat and clean solution.